# Match thickness and placement of lines in vmatrix and bmatrix environments

Tags: matrices, arrays, brackets

I would like to fix this error:

```
$$\begin{matrix}
\left\lceil \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right\rceil
\begin{vmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{vmatrix}
\left\lfloor \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right\rfloor
\end{matrix}$$
```

Using something like this:

```
$$\begin{matrix}
\left\lceil \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right\rceil
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\left\lfloor \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right\rfloor
\end{matrix},$$
```

but without the heads on the brackets.  I think it would come down to using a different line type for the vmatrix environment.

Here is an image to supplement the dilemma:

[image]

Here is the MWE to generate this image:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\frac{(-1)^\beta}{x_\beta} 
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{\alpha-1} & & \left\lceil\begin{matrix} -x_1/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\alpha-1}/x_\beta \end{matrix}\right\rceil & \\
& \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \\ & I_{\beta - \alpha} & \\ & & \end{bmatrix} &  \begin{matrix} -1/x_\beta \\ -x_\alpha/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\beta-1}/x_\beta \end{matrix} & \\
& & \left\lfloor\begin{matrix} -x_{\beta + 1}/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_n/x_\beta \end{matrix}\right\rfloor & I_{n - \beta}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

And this is a better description of what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: What does this matrix supposed to look like? Is it a block diagonal matrix?

Comment: @percusse Yes that's right.  I want matching vertical lines to join the content in the third column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rule:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{(-1)^\beta}{x_\beta} 
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{\alpha-1} & & 
   \left\lceil\begin{matrix}
   -x_1/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\alpha-1}/x_\beta
   \end{matrix}\right\rceil
\\
& \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \\ & I_{\beta - \alpha} & \\ & &
  \end{bmatrix} &
  \vrule width 3pt \kern 2.3pt \begin{matrix}
  -1/x_\beta \\ -x_\alpha/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\beta-1}/x_\beta
  \end{matrix} \kern 2.3pt \vrule width 3pt \\
& & 
  \left\lfloor\begin{matrix}
  -x_{\beta + 1}/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_n/x_\beta
  \end{matrix}\right\rfloor & I_{n - \beta}
\end{bmatrix}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different hack (don't ask about `\valign`, please):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{(-1)^\beta}{x_\beta}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vcenter{\hbox{\valign{#\cr
  \vskip1em
  \hbox{$I_{\alpha-1}$\hskip\arraycolsep}
  \vfill\cr
  \vfill
  \hbox{\hskip\arraycolsep$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \\ & I_{\beta - \alpha} & \\ & &
    \end{bmatrix}
  $\hskip\arraycolsep}
  \vfill\cr
  \hbox{\hskip\arraycolsep$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -x_1/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\alpha-1}/x_\beta \\
    -1/x_\beta \\ -x_\alpha/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\beta-1}/x_\beta \\
    -x_{\beta + 1}/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_n/x_\beta
    \end{bmatrix}
  $\hskip\arraycolsep}\cr
  \vfill
  \hbox{\hskip\arraycolsep$I_{n - \beta}$}
  \vskip1em\cr
}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A less fun solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{(-1)^\beta}{x_\beta}
\begin{blockarray}{[cc[c]c]}
& & -x_1/x_\beta & \\
I_{\alpha-1} & & \vdots & \\
& & -x_{\alpha-1}/x_\beta & \\
& 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \\ & I_{\beta - \alpha} & \\ & &
  \end{bmatrix}
&
  \begin{matrix}
  -1/x_\beta \\ -x_\alpha/x_\beta \\ \vdots \\ -x_{\beta-1}/x_\beta \\
  \end{matrix}
& \\
& & -x_{\beta + 1}/x_\beta & \\
& & \vdots & I_{n - \beta} \\ 
& & -x_n/x_\beta & 
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You took the picture quite literally but I played with the numbers and got it to look satisfactory.  Thanks!

Comment: @OpenSeason Is the second one better? `;-)`

Comment: Beautiful! I appreciate it a lot.